# SVN Authentication issue

Tags: linux, svn, centos, tortoisesvn

I have configured `SVN` in my Centos server but i faced a problem , i cannot authorize, when i enter `username` and `password` in authorization form, this form asking username and password again! It seems username and password is not valid or something is wrong, unfortunately i could not found problem!

**Here are my server configurations  :**
SVN Directory : /svn

```
/sv/app/conf/svnserve.conf

[general]

anon-access = none
auth-access = read
auth-access = write

[sasl]
```

AND

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf

LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath  /svn  
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/acl
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authorization Realm"
   AuthUserFile /svn/newrep.users
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And i have access to repository from `http://example.com/repos/app/`

I have generated users & password via below command :

```
htpasswd -cm /svn/newrep.users username
```

And ACL file

```
/svn/acl


[groups]
ksoft = ali, morteza

[/]
@ksoft = rw
```

P.S : I tested everything, for example different options in configuration files, but i did not get answer!

Comment: Show results of any command in CLI (it's betterfordebug and more informative, than GUI-way)

Answer (score 2):

1. You **must** to read books, at least SVN Book, *before* crying and asking questions: it will be a lot easier for everybody.

   - `REPO//conf/svnserve.conf` do **nothing** and **not used** in case of http-served repository
   - `auth-access = write` **assumes** also `auth-access = read` (i.e. additional auth-access directive is just useless)
2. Can't recall strict recommendations in SVN Book, but I, by default, prefer to have

> ```
> [/]
> * = TYPE-OF-ACCESS-RIGHTS
> ```

in `AuthzSVNAccessFile` before less-specific rules